# Prove that any subgroup of the center $Z(G)$ of $G$ is a normal subgroup of $G$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups

**Q.** Prove that any subgroup of the center $Z(G)$ of $G$ is a normal subgroup of $G$.

When proving "If $G$ is a $p$-group of order $p^l$, then $G$ has a normal subgroup
of order $p^k$ for every $k ≤ l$.", the author seems to use the statement that  any subgroup of the center $Z(G)$ of $G$ is a normal subgroup of $G$.

I have proved that $Z(G)$ is a normal subgroup of $G$, if we pick any subgroup of $Z(G)$, how to show that it is also a normal subgroup of $G$ ? I want to take *conjugates* but I am stuck here

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please include your question in the body of the question, instead of putting it only in the title.

Comment: Which book are you referring to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $H < Z(G)$. Recall that $Z(G) = \{g \in G : gh = hg \hspace{0.1cm} \forall \hspace{0.1cm}h \in G\}$.

(You can multiply by $g^{-1}$ in the definition to have $ghg^{-1}=h$ if you prefer to see conjugancy here)

Now take $g \in G$, for any $h \in H$, in particular $H \in Z(G)$ hence $ghg^{-1}= h$, in other words you said that $gHg^{-1} = H$ for every $g \in G$ and $h \in H$, hence $H$ is normal in $G$.

Answer (score 5):

Let $H$ be such a subgroup and let $h \in H$. Then, for all $g \in G$, $g h g^{-1} = h g g^{-1} = h \in H$. Therefore, $H$ is normal.

Answer (score 2):

Everything in the center commutes with every other element of the group.  So if $H\le Z (G)$, we easily get for any $g\in G $ that $gHg^{-1}=gg^{-1}H=H $.